# Firestore adding hashmaps to a map field in Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a map of objects in my firestore database using key->value pairs. 
The idea is to have a map of room objects within my Properties documents where living room would be the key and the object that value. Like the image below

[image: rooms map]

[image: rooms map]

I am getting lost with the correct way to add the objects into firestore as the rooms map is already there so how do I add a key->value pair into it ?? 
I also need to perform the search I have in the below code so I can grab the Properties document and add the objects into the room map field

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
final CollectionReference propertyRef = db.collection("Properties");

final Room room = new Room(roomName, feet, inches, imageUrl);

propertyRef.whereEqualTo("propertyId", propertyId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
              propertyRef.document(doc.getId())
     ----->   .update("rooms", ""+roomName+"", room);

              Log.d(TAG, "Firebase Success= " + imageUrl);
              Toast.makeText(CreatePropertyActivity3.this, "Property Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              exProperties();
              }
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(CreatePropertyActivity3.this, "Error check log", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `document(String)` method on the `db`, which as per docs will create the document if it does not exist (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

```
Map<String, Object> room = new HashMap<>();
room.put("feet", "...");
...

db.collection("rooms").document("the new room id")
        .set(room)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                  ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFalureListener(...)
```

This is if you know the IDs of your documents, or want to set the ID yourself. If so, you can replace the argument passed to `.document(...)` before adding a new item. Alternatively, you could use the `add()` method which will create a new document with an auto-generated ID for you.

In your case, it seems as though you are setting your own meaningful ids (e.g. livingroom, kitchen) and you should be changing the `propertyId` variable before adding a map. However, that is redundant since you already have an attribute (i.e. name) that describes the room. So use `add()` and avoid querying for a document that would not exist to begin with:

```
final HashMap<String, Object> newRoom = new HashMap<>();
newRoom.put(roomName, room);
...
propertyRef.add(newRoom)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
        }
    });
```

In fact, because you were using `whereEqualTo` you were always fetching a reference to the same document and overwriting its content. Just use the `add()` functionality and check the docs for more examples. Hope that helps!

Comment: My apologies for not explaining clearer please see my updated question. I am using whereEqualTo to grab the correct Properties document so I can then add to the room map field within that document